# FBX Binary Export Action Issue

Tags: animation, export, .fbx, actions

I have a model with multiple animation 'actions', destined to be used in Unity3D.

Most of the actions export from Blender and import into Unity fine.

There are three actions, though, do not export from Blender unless the action is selected in the action editor, which means the other two do not export at all.

What would prevent an action from being exported unless it was currently selected? I can see no difference between these three actions and the other ones that export correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else having this issue, I resolved it by removing some keyframes from the offending actions that were related to bones that no longer existed.

FBX exporter ignores actions if there are any errors in them, and I guess having those extra keyframes for non existent bones was messing it up.

If you have missing actions, check that all of your keyframes are related to existing bones.

Comment: pks you're my hero, thanks ;)

Comment: Ahh Man, I wonder if this is what has been causing me soooo much pain

Comment: This was making me nuts! Thanks!